# Load testing - Run C# selenium scripts in Jmeter

Tags: c#, selenium, jmeter, mstest, load-testing

I have a MSTest project with Selenium test cases in C#.

[image]

I saw that Jmeter used to work with Java Selenium scripts. how can I make a load testing running those C# scripts into Jmeter for multiple users at the same time?

The output only generates a .DLL for the project.

Answer (score 1):

[CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) are "alien" so you won't be able to run C# tests in JMeter.

Moreover using real browsers for load testing is not the best idea as browsers are very resource intensive (1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM for [latest Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/84.0.1/system-requirements/)) so you the number of virtual users you will be able to simulate this way is way too limited comparing with [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTP) based load tests which resource footprint is much less. Moreover you won't get metrics you can analyze

So the options are in:

1. Run your [MSTest solution in command-line mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms182487(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) in multi-threaded manner using [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) (however this way you won't be able to get good results for analysis as JMeter won't know anything about hits per second and response times)
2. Convert your MSTest solution into "pure" JMeter test, the options are in:

   - [Configure Selenium to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/) and replay your tests via JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), this way you will get the requests originating from the browser converted to JMeter's [HTTP Request samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which can be replayed with increased load
   - This option is pretty much the same as the above but it assumes some more automation, you can execute your tests via [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool and use its [Proxy2JMX subsystem](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) for tests conversion